# jQuery datetimepicker not initializing in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker

I am trying to initialize a datetimepicker but I am always getting an error:

```
 $(...).timepicker not a function
```

My code is as follow:

```
 //REFERENCES:

 <link href="/CSS/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

  //JAVASCRIPT

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('"[id*=tb_input]"').timepicker();

  function tpicker() {
    $('"[id*=tb_input]"').timepicker();
  }
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(tpicker);
  </script>

  //HTML
  <asp:TextBox ID="tb_input" style="text-align:center" runat="server"
   CssClass="font2" Width="226px" onfocus="disableautocompletion(this.id);"
   Height="24px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Refference should be as 
first load jquery core file , then load other files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reorder the scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

Remove following :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

It will just you cost extra page load time .

and Init your datepicker in like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
       InitTimePicker();
    });
```

If you are using updatepanel :

```
function InitTimePicker(){
     $('"[id*=tb_input]"').timepicker();
}
```

and add thi function to end reuqest:)